# Services for phoneme recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition, reference-implementation

I wonder if anyone can point me to services or dev libraries that focus on or suit phoneme recognition? Target audience is children at learning to read stage.

We have trialed IBM Watson (not good) and Google (only a little better).

Hope this is a suitable question for this forum. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is honestly not very suitable question. You'd better ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the way it is phrased is not exactly about DSP but about software recommendation for which there already is a stack exchange board.

Comment: Cool, thanks @NikolayShmyrev for pointing to softwarerecs, didn't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SoapBoxLabs](http://soapboxlabs.com) have very good technology for children, including pronunciation scoring